# Open Same AngularJS application in new window and call function in parent window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been working on an angular application. I have one requirement while where I show list of available tasks to user and clicking on a particular task, open a new window with the same AngularJS application code base, which will allow the user to make changes to the task. The application in new window will be independent and user can perform some actions. Once user closes the window, I need refresh the task list in parent application (parent window).

I am passing some data to child window, the data consist of some properties and one function,

```
var appData = {
                action: "edit",
                id: taskId,
                refreshTasks: refreshTasks
            };
```

Refresh task is a method in my one of the controller

I am passing the data to the child window in following manner,

```
var windowHandle = $window.open("http://www.example.com"); 
if(angular.isDefined(windowHandle)) {
     windowHandle.appData = (dataObj == null ? {} : dataObj);
     windowHandle.appData.isChildWindow = true;
}
```

Now we access the passed data in child window using,

```
$window.appData
```

Now when child window closes, I am invoking my passed function in following manner,

```
$window.appData.refreshTasks()
```

The above seems to work in Chrome and Mozilla but its not working in IE (8,9,10,11)

So I really wanted to know how I can call function from one angular application in one window to another angular application in another window.

Can you kindly let me know what is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `appData` using `window.opener`:

```
window.opener.appData
window.opener.appData.refreshTasks()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still this does not work. Is it that I have to send data like below `windowHanlde.opener.appData` ?

Comment: the above mention codes will work if appData is global variable in parent window

Comment: Its not global variable. That is what my question is about, how can I call the function in one of my controller from child window.

Comment: so appData is defined inside a controller?

Comment: No AppData I form  after opening window and assign it to the child window's reference `windowHandle.appData` you can see in my code above I have explained. But however I tried creating a global function in my parent window and tried calling it from child window like this `window.opener.myParentWindowFunc()` but this too does not work.

Comment: No no error.The point is I am closing window when user clicks on "Save" button. I tried debugging the code and when the debugger hits break point , I tried calling my global function in parent window and found that until child window is open it triggers function (calling function in child window's console) but in normal execution (without debugger) its not invoking. Not sure what is going wrong.